# Skip initial spaces with numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I'm trying to read CSV files into Python with the numpy package. My row data has several entries such as 'VA, no longer in study'. The issue is that if I use np.genfromtxt to read in the file with ',' as the delimiter, it separates such entries as ['VA', 'no longer in study'] as opposed to ['VA, no longer in study']. Is there an option in the genfromtxt function that could help me avoid this issue or create a dialect allowing me to skip over these initial spaces?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: must numpy be used to solve your problem? because something like `pandas`, which works alongside numpy, could handle this well.

Comment: `genfromtxt` does not handle quoted strings.  The `csv` module does.  You could also preprocess the file, changing for example the real delimiters to something else.

Comment: Wait, you are trying to create an array of *strings*?